# Facebook Sign in - Use app if installed?

Tags: android, ios, facebook, mobile, oauth

I've got a facebook login working for my web application (browser based). It works great on desktop, but I'm looking for something a bit different for mobile and tablet.

So, as much as the app does work on mobile and tablet, I'm looking for a way to check if the user has the facebook app installed, if they do use that, otherwise load in a new tab (which is how it is currently behaving).

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I didn't get a response to this, but ended up doing some research instead that I'll abridge here in case this helps anyone.

More or less, Facebook works better by just signing in through the browser instead of bothering with the app. Fair enough, the user may already be signed in on the app, but they will only ever have to sign in once via browser - then any time they visit a site with Facebook integration after, they will still be signed in.

Hope this helps someone!